# Ember Observe DOM Element

Tags: dom, ember.js

I have an

```html
<input type="file">
```

in my DOM. Is it possible to trigger an action with Ember techniques if the file in this input changes, or do I have to use third party libs like jquery-observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible.

You can create a file field component as follows:

```
// put in components/file-field.js if you are using ember-cli

import Ember from "ember"

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',
    attributeBindings: ['multiple'],
    multiple: false,
    change: function(event) {
        var input = event.target();
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(input.files)) {
            this.sendAction("filesChanged", input.files);
        }
    }
});
```

Now place this in your template in place of your <input type="file">

```
{{file-field filesChanged="uploadFile"}}
```

Then in the controller or in one of your routes where this action will bubble, define your uploadFile action:

```
actions: {
    uploadFile: function(files) {
        // put your ajax call to upload the file(s) here
    }
}
```

Although this is enough to get you started learning, I would definitely recommend using something like [ember-cli-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-cli-uploader) for this in a real application.